# "That be me" in the movie The Hateful Eight

Tags: phrase-meaning, connotations

I watched Tarantino's The Hateful Eight and heard the following dialogue between Major Marquis Warren and John Ruth:

> - I know you too.
> - We shared a steak dinner once upon a time in Chattanooga.
> - You John Ruth, the hangman.
> - That be me

So for me, John Ruth phrase sounds pretty strange like there is a skipped word like *will* or *would*. Is there really a skipped word? If yes why is it skipped? Maybe it's common for dialects?

What is a difference from just "Yes it's me"? I suppose the meaning is the same, but nuances are different. Did John Ruth wish to sound kind of peculiar saying this, or maybe it's just a common way of saying that in the context of the movie?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right. That would be incorrect English, but the thing is that that's not what he actually says. He does say it using correct English grammar: *That'd be me.* He doesn't skip anything. *That'd* is just a contraction of *that would*. Do you understand? It's just that the subtitles that you're using are not of very good quality. Listen closely to [**this short audio clip**](https://vocaroo.com/i/s1TYkEeX3OME) that I copied from the movie for you.

Comment: Hmm, in subtitles I downloaded from the first link in google it's written _that be me_. Yes I understand what is contraction, I just can't hear that _'d_ distinctly, no matter how many attempts I make, it seems that I just don't have enough practice of hearing that way of speech to distinguish this. Thank You.

Comment: @Vitaly Don't worry. You'll get there one day.